# Proper syntax in PHP on form element

Tags: php, syntax

New to PHP-

If I have PHP getting a picture name from a form:

```
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
```

and I want to reference that field dynamically later in the file (sample_name.jpg):

```
$resizeObj = new resize('images/sample_name.jpg');
```

What is the proper formating?

Using `$resizeObj = new resize('images/'$pic'');` gives me a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
$resizeObj = new resize('images/'.$pic);
```

`.` means [string concatenation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$resizeObj = new resize("images/$pic");
```

instead, and read [this nice introduction to strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
$resizeObj = new resize('images/'.$pic);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 2 ways

```
$resizeObj = new resize("images/$pic");
```

or

```
$resizeObj = new resize('images/'.$pic);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

```
$resizeObj = new resize("images/$pic");
```

is the most common, but I personally don't like variables in strings, so you could go with:

```
$resizeObj = new resize('images/'. $pic);
```

Or even

```
$resizeObj = new resize(sprintf('images/%s', $pic));
```